# Why is/isn't a topological Basis unique?

Tags: general-topology

Is the basis for a particular topology on a particular set unique? Why or why not?

Comment: Compare $\mathbb{R}$ with basis being the open ball and basis being the open sets.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I disagree. This is a textbook example of "missing context or other details"

Comment: @AlexKruckman I didn't vote to close, but I'm guessing people want the question to include thoughts on the problem and any attempts made to solve it.

Comment: @avid19 I'm not sure what context or other details I could have added. If you have something in particular I can add it now?

Comment: @P.Jain For example, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts to had to solve it. Problem statements with no accompanying information tend to be received poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general many different bases can generate the same topology.

One easy way to see this is that given a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, $\tau$ itself (the collection of all open sets) is a basis for $\tau$. So if $\tau$ admits a basis that isn't the collection of *all* open sets, then it admits multiple bases.

So, for example, $B_1 = \{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}\mid U\text{ open}\}$ and $B_2 = \{(a,b)\mid a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ are both bases for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Nor do I understand the downvote. Explain?

Comment: Vandalism. ${}$

Comment: @alexKruckman Thanks! :)